# How to give the max item of a dictionary given a value somewhere in an array in the value?

Tags: python, dictionary

In python, say I have a dictionary

```
{1:[1,333], 2:[5,22], 3:[8:0]}
```

I want to return the max item in the dictionary by the second item in the value array, so in this case, 333 beats all the rest numbers in the same place, I wish the function can return

```
(1,[1,33])
```

Is there any neat way to implement this using `max()` with key or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> d = {1:[1,333], 2:[5,22], 3:[8, 0]}
>>> max(d.items(), key=lambda e: e[1][1])
(1, [1, 333])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the `key` argument to `max()`, i.e.:

```
d = {1:[1,333], 2:[5,22], 3:[8,0]}
# Use d[k][1] so that max is based on the second
#   item in each list
max_key = max(d, key=lambda k: d[k][1])
print((max_key, d[max_key]))
(1, [1, 333])
```